# Installing node-canvas on EC2 - fontconfig.h build error

Tags: node.js, canvas, amazon-ec2, node-canvas

I am trying to get `node-canvas` to build via `npm install` on an AWS EC2 instance. I'm trying to use the latest (Feb 2016) version of canvas, `1.3.10`

I followed the instructions outlined here:
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Amazon-Linux-AMI-(EC2)

And seemingly got libpng, jpeg, pixman, freetype and cairo installed fine.

I then did:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

`sudo yum install giflib-devel`

to fix some build errors, and once again tried an npm install.

Now the build is failing due to a missing file error:

```
make: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/signal/app/node_modules/canvas/build'
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
  COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasGradient.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasPattern.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/color.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Image.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/ImageData.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/FontFace.o
../src/FontFace.cc:9:35: fatal error: fontconfig/fontconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #include <fontconfig/fontconfig.h>
```

What am I missing here? I can find this file on my local OSX (where canvas is running fine), under `opt/X11/include/fontconfig` - how do I ship that up to EC2 in a sensible way? Otherwise, how might I work round this problem?

Massive thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to install `fontconfig-devel` via yum to resolve that dependency